# How do I add a CAA record?

Tags: ssl, dns

The [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com) service awarded my domain an A

However, it flagged that there is no CAA record set for my domain.

This article explains I can set a CAA record for my domain which will restrict my CA to lets encrypt only.

https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/caa-record/#caa-record-usage

So I need to add the following CAA record:

```
example.com.  CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
```

So I logged into the GoDaddy web console BUT there is not option to add a CAA record! grrrr

Does anyone know how I can do this using the GoDaddy Web UI? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many DNS providers do NOT support CAA yet.
They might or might not be implementing it.
You should ask GoDaddy for status update about it.

Comment: Is it possible to use a `TXT` record instead?

Comment: Nope. CAA records are their own DNS RR record type (type 257).